# Scrollbar Free website layout in all resolutions using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a strange requirement for a web application (single page web app) in which the page shouldn't have a scrollbar. The header & footer stays sticky & the middle content part should adjust(keeping proportion) without scrollbar in any resolution. Following is a preview of the layout.

[image]

Live Demo - https://previewin.xyz/web/sree/layout/

CodePen Demo - https://codepen.io/DeCodeUI/pen/gZBXqa

**CSS**

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 500;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 500;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 60px 15px;
}

#grid {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

**HTML Sample**

```html
<div id="page">

  <header>Text</header>

  <div id="content">

    <div id="grid">
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
      <div class="grid-item"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>Text</footer>

</div>
```

Those 9 grids in blue, always keep proportion in any resolution & no scrollbars. I have tried my best & the result is here - https://previewin.xyz/web/sree/layout/  but when the screen get smaller, the grids won't resize. Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the container `width:100%` and set `max-width:1160px` based on your requirement in your code. If you set width for container responsive and browser resize become problem. I hope this solution will work for you.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1160px;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 500;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 500;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#content {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 60px 15px;
}
#grid {
    max-width: 900px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid-item {
   width: 150px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
   margin: 10px;
   padding:30px;
   color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div class="container">
        <header>Text</header>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="grid">
                <div class="grid-item">1</div>
                <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                <div class="grid-item">5</div>
                <div class="grid-item">6</div>
                <div class="grid-item">7</div>
                <div class="grid-item">8</div>
                <div class="grid-item">9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>Text</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't help. It stills create scrollbar in some resolution. I have tried css zoom: property it helps in achieving the result I'm looking for, but it's not supported in Firefox.